# Edit dll file without sourceCode

Tags: file, editing

we want to edit one dll file that write with C#. I check the file with reflector and want to change just the connection string password field to new password.
How can I edit this without accessing to source code or recompiling the file?

Answer (score 6):

Try [Reflexil](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/), a plugin for reflector than can modify IL code.

Comment: it just let me rename the connection string and inject the class, interface, struc,... I want to just edit the password=

Comment: I just tried it myself. You can modify string variables in Reflexil. I saved the modifed dll and looked in Reflector at the disassembler code and it showed the modifed string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck.  This is a good example of why such items need to be referenced in external resources.

EDIT: though I've never tried it, the comment from @Testalino regarding [Reflexil](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/) looks promising.

Comment: it didn't let me to change the password field